# Parsing editing and saving js file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript file which contains an array of objects. That array also contains some functions as objects. So keep in mind I can't use JSON parsing as it will return an error. Now I need to read that js file and access that array and add one more function as an object in that array and save it to a hard disk. Is there any parsing library which can help me with that and how?

Here is the js file

```
let notifications = {
"Welcome": {
    title: "Welcome",
    body: "",
    icon: ""
}};

let script = {
"Start": [
    "notify Welcome",
    {
        "Input": {
            "Text": "What is your name?",
            "Validation": function (input) {
                return input.trim().length > 0;
            },
            "Save": function (input) {
                storage.player.Name = input;
                return true;
            },
            "Warning": "You must enter a name!"
        }
    },

    "h Hi {{player.Name}} Welcome!",

    "h Currently you have {{player.intelligence}} points of Intelligence but you seem far more intelligent, how about we add five points?",
    {"Function":{
        "Apply": function () {
            storage.player.intelligence += 5;
            return true;
        },

        "Reverse": function () {
            storage.player.intelligence -= 5;
        }
    }},
    "h There you have it, you now have {{player.intelligence}} points of Intelligence",

    {
        "Choice": {
            "Dialog": "h Have you already read some documentation?",
            "Yes": {
                "Text": "Yes",
                "Do": "jump Yes"
            },
            "No": {
                "Text": "No",
                "Do": "jump No"
            }
        }
    }
],

"Yes": [

    "h That's awesome!",
    "h Then you are ready to go ahead and create an amazing Game!",
    "h I can't wait to see what story you'll tell!",
    "end"
],

"No": [

    "h You can do it now.",

    "display message Help",

    "h Go ahead and create an amazing Game!",
    "h I can't wait to see what story you'll tell!",
    "end"
]};
```

Now I need to add some more choices in scripts array programmatically and save it.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [JSON-fn](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/jsonfn). It can be used to do the following:

> Javascript (both node.js and browser) plugin to stringify / parse / clone jsvascript objects with
>
> - Functions
> - RegExp
> - Date

Comment: This is a handy tool indeed. But it doesn't help me to parse full js files a d get individual variables.